# Create ntp time stamp from gettimeofday

Tags: c++, c, networking, unix, ntp

I need to calculate an ntp time stamp using gettimeofday. Below is how I've done it with comments on method. Look good to you guys? (minus error checking). Also, here's a [codepad](http://codepad.org/1zHEon54) link.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

const unsigned long EPOCH = 2208988800UL; // delta between epoch time and ntp time
const double NTP_SCALE_FRAC = 4294967295.0; // maximum value of the ntp fractional part

int main()
{
  struct timeval tv;
  uint64_t ntp_time;
  uint64_t tv_ntp;
  double tv_usecs;

  gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
  tv_ntp = tv.tv_sec + EPOCH;

  // convert tv_usec to a fraction of a second
  // next, we multiply this fraction times the NTP_SCALE_FRAC, which represents
  // the maximum value of the fraction until it rolls over to one. Thus,
  // .05 seconds is represented in NTP as (.05 * NTP_SCALE_FRAC)
  tv_usecs = (tv.tv_usec * 1e-6) * NTP_SCALE_FRAC;

  // next we take the tv_ntp seconds value and shift it 32 bits to the left. This puts the 
  // seconds in the proper location for NTP time stamps. I recognize this method has an 
  // overflow hazard if used after around the year 2106
  // Next we do a bitwise OR with the tv_usecs cast as a uin32_t, dropping the fractional
  // part
  ntp_time = ((tv_ntp << 32) | (uint32_t)tv_usecs);
}
```

Comment: can i ask why you multiply tv_usec with NTP_SCALE_FRAC? to me, it seems trasnforming usec to pico seconds (*10^6) should be sufficient, maybe i am missing something?

Comment: In NTP, if I understand correctly, the fraction portion is represented as a fraction of the total possible values. So it's not a 1-to-1.

For example, if I represent one second in 1000 parts, then someone gives me a value of .5 seconds with base 60, I'd have to scale that to my on base 1000. 

With NTP, the base is the 32 bit representation it's transformed into. So 1 second = 2^32 ntp fraction seconds.

Comment: Thanks, I understand this. What is not apparent to me is why
tv_usecs = (NTP_SCALE_FRAC * tv.tv_usec) / 1000000UL
does the job?

Comment: Lifting a part of the formula that will always equal a known *constant* value. Say your cows produce 200 liters of milk a day (constant). The kings tax-collector demands a *variable* percentage of your daily milk production each day. Elementary school teaches: percentage * total / 100 (100 because it is per cent, not per million). Today he wants 25%, so 25*200/100=50. Rings a bell? Math tells us that (in base/radix-10) division by 10  is simply moving the decimal marker.. Thus (25*200)/100 = (25/100)*200 = 25*(200/100) = 50 **so** constant 200 / constant 100 = constant 2. Hence 25 * 2 !!!

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use `uint64_t` here - `unsigned long long` is guaranteed to be at least 64 bits wide.

You also don't need to go to and from `double`, since `NTP_SCALE_FRAC * 1000000` will easily fit in an `unsigned long long`.

`EPOCH` should be `unsigned long long`, not `unsigned long`, so that the addition with `tv.tv_sec` doesn't wrap around.

All up:

```
const unsigned long long EPOCH = 2208988800ULL;
const unsigned long long NTP_SCALE_FRAC = 4294967296ULL;

unsigned long long tv_to_ntp(struct timeval tv)
{
    unsigned long long tv_ntp, tv_usecs;

    tv_ntp = tv.tv_sec + EPOCH;
    tv_usecs = (NTP_SCALE_FRAC * tv.tv_usec) / 1000000UL;

    return (tv_ntp << 32) | tv_usecs;
}
```

Comment: I might be misunderstanding, but the spec for long long is that it's at least 64, but could be more. I have to do some byte swapping on the results (network byte order), so I wanted to more tightly constrain the size.

Comment: Yes, it could be more.  If you need to manipulate the underlying representation (say, to stuff it into a network packet), then using `uint64_t` is appropriate, but you should generally limit that use to the network-handling packing/unpacking code itself.

Comment: Off by 1.  `NTP_SCALE_FRAC` should be `4294967296ULL`, or even better just use `tv_usecs = ((unsigned long long)tv.tv_usec << 32) / 1000000ULL;`.

Answer (score 1):

```
extern uint64_t tvtontp64(struct timeval *tv) {
    uint64_t ntpts;

    ntpts = (((uint64_t)tv->tv_sec + 2208988800u) << 32) + ((uint32_t)tv->tv_usec * 4294.967296);

    return (ntpts);
}
```

I'm using 4294.967296 not ...5 as it is a ratio to the total count 0 needs to be counted
4294967296 ticks per second or 4294.967296 per usec its simple to verify this as 1000000 usec will be a overflow [to seconds] the range of ticks should be 0 to (1000000-1).

This is a simplification and suitable for my purpose 
Unique Local IPv6 Unicast Addresses [RFC4193]